# Zipfian vs Uniform - What's the difference between these two YCSB distribution?

Tags: benchmarking, ycsb, nosql

Can anyone please describe the differences between Zipfian and Uniform distribution while running YCSB workloads ?

Here's the YCSB core properties: https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Core-Properties

Answer (score 9):

The Yahoo Team has explained it in their [paper](https://b9f6702a-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/brianfrankcooper/home/publications/ycsb.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cpe_58QdQT2zmkyB9S3xwyueiVd_ph9gxBvuX5gvv43udlR0ju5gCBlopniMuS9giN8OXSnW3FvAvGPrWCvoKNY54SCjCQn2bwV7H7FS-F5R1j6oP0BQEQG-BHqrVuh9dJKuQsFp8wVHSh-U12nS4eb5wC4q0_MriEWH5k3KNZKpg63i2Xfu_YfSBNnzFk47zFp1_IJakmz0tDheYQvPNNlIkutiwip_cGy_B4h26xe_lUR2u8%3D&attredirects=0).

In a nutshell, the distribution affects how YCSB reads and scans over the keyspace:

- `uniform`: each row has an equal probability to be read
- `zipfian`: some rows have more probability to be targeted by reads or scans. Those rows are called "hot set" or "hot spot" and represent popular data, for instance popular threads of a forum. You should set it up with: `hotspotdatafraction` and `hotspotopnfraction`. See `$YCSB_HOME/workloads/workload_template` for more details.

Hope this helps.